# Students' misbehaviour "has" or "have"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects

> Students' misbehaviour **has/have** worsened in the past few years.

Is it *has* or *have*? Or can both be correct with "has" referring to "misbehaviour" and "have" referring to students?

I'm inclined towards "has".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96982/discussion-on-question-by-antonio-conte-students-misbehaviour-has-or-have).

Answer (score 3):

Only *has* is correct:

> Students' misbehaviour **has** worsened in the past few years.

"Students' misbehaviour" is a noun phrase. It refers to a type of misbehaviour: the noun "misbehaviour" is what is called the [head](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/phrases/ex2.htm) of this noun phrase. In general, the type of agreement that a noun phrase takes is based on the type of noun that it has as a head. Noun phrases headed by the noun *misbehaviour* take singular agreement.

It is not grammatical to replace *has* with *have* in this sentence, even if you mean to refer to students.

"Misbehaviour" is also the head of the noun phrases "The misbehaviour of the students" and "The student's misbehaviour", so those would also take *has*:

- The misbehaviour of the students **has** worsened in the past few years.
- The student's misbehaviour **has** worsened in the past few years.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96983/discussion-on-answer-by-sumelic-students-misbehaviour-has-or-have).