# Is"That the messages are written in simplified Chinese...confirm that the intended audience is Chinese tourists." correct?

Tags: word-order

Methinks the sentence does not sound natural. I also think that there should be ***confirms*** instead of ***confirm*** ([source](https://qz.com/1660460/hong-kong-protesters-use-airdrop-to-breach-chinas-firewall/)):

> That the messages are written in simplified Chinese—Hong Kongers use traditional Chinese—confirm that the intended audience **is** Chinese tourists.

I would rewrite it by changing the word order:

> That the messages are written in simplified Chinese—Hong Kongers use traditional Chinese—confirms that Chinese tourists are the intended audience.

Other than ***confirm***, is the original sentence correct with regards to the word order? Does the rewritten sentence sound more natural to you?Is it correct? If not, how would you rewrite it?

Comment: *The audience* is singular, and so takes *is*.

Comment: In the UK, *audience* could be considered plural. (But rarely in the US.) So, it depends.

Comment: @sumelic isnt *are* incorrect because for this type of NP it follows a singular verb? Like you said in this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/401150/students-misbehaviour-has-or-have/507076#507076)

Comment: But it's grammatical on whether *audience* is *considered* plural...interesting.

Comment: @Peter Shor I won't counter with '_The audience_ here is obviously intended to be an accepted shorthand for _the members of the audience_, and so takes _are_' because then, like you, I'd be violating the Gricean Maxim of Quantity.

Comment: I'd question **confirm**'s correctness.

Comment: @aesking: My answer there doesn't say anything about this sentence. *Behaviour* and *audience* are different nouns. I didn't talk about a general "type of NP" in my linked answer, only about NPs headed by the specific noun *behaviour*. As Edwin and Jason said in their comments, NPs headed by the noun *audience* might be able to take plural agreement (as a form of "notional agreement"). By the way, you can't use @ to notify someone who hasn't posted or commented above you in the same thread. I only saw your comment because this question came up in review.